# Jackson: Map<String, Object> serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

Is it possible to serialize/deserialize `Map<String, Object>` where type of object (mapped value) would be determined by its key.

```
{
    "number":42,
    "desc":"something really important",
    "location":{
        "x":9999,
        "y":9999,
        "wkid":9999
    },
    "shape":{
        "type":"polyline",
        "data":"dGhpcyBnZW9tZXRyeSBpcyBmYWtlIDpQ"
    }
}
```

In this particular case I know that `desc` is always going to be `string`, `location` and `shape` - 3rd party classes (I have serializers and deserializers for them) and other values are boxed primitives.

Is it possible to do something like this with jackson? Could such thing be done by using MapSerializer/MapDeserializer? (I couldn't find any examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I would recommend you to try [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Just paste you `JSON` and select source type `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be done.
Have another structure that contains a pair of `Map<String, Class>` and link the key name of the first structure (`Map<String, Object>`) to the second one.

For example

```
Map map = new HashMap<String, Object>();`

map.put("desc", "something really important");

Map deser = new HashMap<String, Class>();

deser.put("desc", StringDeserializer.class);
```

You could also use a `deser<String, String>`, where the value would be the class name, then you just do a class loading by name http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_forname_loader.htm

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific (how should the `deser` map be connected to ObjectReader/Mapper)?

Comment: if you are not using the Jackson registry then you are doing it manually. If you are doing it manually then it would be something like: Deserializer des = getDeser(key); /* an example of key would be "desc" */; public Object getDeser(String key) { return deser.get(key);}